# Why Biber does not create bbl file?

Tags: biblatex, biber, ubuntu

I am using TexLive full 2017 on Linux Mint 19 Tara machine. I have installed biber 2.9 as well.  All works fine when I have backend as bibtex but when change that to biber, this does not create bib file. When I run bibliography on the file, it caused an error message saying that,

```
Error: One command expansion invalid.
    Parent Command: bibliography
    Primary Command: bibliography
```

What would be the problem?

**Note:**

I use Texstudio as my front end and I didnt forget the change the `Default bibliography tool` as `biber` in my configuration settings.

### Here is the MWEB.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend = biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is my [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hlC7x4Wy1AMDanfpgDrhoZbGy7YTJQ-P/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: According to your `.log` file you are running `biblatex` 3.10. The corresponding Biber version would be 2.10 and not 2.9. How did you install Biber? I assume your TeX live was installed via `apt-get`? Why don't you install Biber that way as well, then the versions should match.

Comment: @moewe `apt-get` installs biber 2.9-1 only...

Comment: And how did you install `biblatex`? Surely the versions of `biblatex` and Biber installed via `apt-get` should match...

Comment: I have installed `texlive-full` via synaptic package manager..and run `apt-get install texlive-full` after your comment. It says that the current version is upto date..Should I do`apt-get install biblatex`?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it seems that the repositories for Bionic Beaver (Ubuntu 18.04) contain `texlive-base` in version `2017.20180305-1` (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/texlive-base) with `biblatex` 3.10.

But at the same time the Biber version in the repositories is 2.9 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/biber).

Those two versions are incompatible per the `biblatex`/Biber compatibility matrix that can be found in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) or the [Biber manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf).

There already is a bug open for that issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biber/+bug/1770516 and I suggest you add a comment that this is indeed a serious problem that needs to be resolved.

For the time being I only see two work-arounds

1. Get Biber 2.10 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/2.10/binaries/ and install it manually. Usually manual installs are *strongly* discouraged, but desperate times call for desperate measures.
2. Completely remove the TeX live from the Ubuntu repositories and install a vanilla TeX live from TUG instead. See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). The advantage of vanilla TeX live is that you can use `tlmgr` to update your packages.

Comment: +1 for "desperate times call for desperate measures". :-)

Comment: I did installed the `vannila` texlive using the link provided. Ofcourse it look lot of time. But when I run `sudo tlmgr update --self` It gave me ```(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

Comment: @David Did you make sure to remove the other TeX live installation *completely*? There were questions with similar symptoms here and all were caused by remnants of the old system hanging around.